# Color Coded Scatter Chart Using Three Different Columns

Tags: python, range, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot, scatter

data = {'member_birth_year':[1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000,2010],
        'member_gender':['male','female', 'other'],
       'user_type':['customer', 'subscriber']}

[image]

Comment: what did you expect?

Comment: Three different colors for each column.

Comment: but your columns are of different length, so what kind of DataFrame did you expect?

Comment: So I should delete member birth year because of the length?